error while building astro on cloudflare pages
When i tried to build my simple astro blog, Cloudflare was unable to build it and gave this error
Cannot bundle Node.js built-in "stream"
the:
2024-10-04T08:47:14.977982Z [commonjs--resolver] [plugin vite:resolve] Cannot bundle Node.js built-in "stream" imported from "node_modules/.pnpm/reading-time@1.5.0/node_modules/reading-time/lib/stream.js". Consider disabling ssr.noExternal or remove the built-in dependency.
2024-10-04T08:47:14.978243Z file: /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/reading-time@1.5.0/node_modules/reading-time/index.js
2024-10-04T08:47:14.97852Z    Stack trace:
2024-10-04T08:47:14.978643Z     at getRollupError (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.24.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:395:41)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.978782Z     at Object.error (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.24.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20545:20)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.978923Z     at Object.handler (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:65596:15)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.979033Z     at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.24.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20630:28)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.979114Z     at async ModuleLoader.resolveId (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.24.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19663:15)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.979179Z     at async Promise.all (index 1)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.979392Z     at async rewriteRequireExpressionsAndGetImportBlock (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.4.8/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:13599:28)
2024-10-04T08:47:14.979545Z     at async transform (file:///opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.24.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19581:16)

complete log is here: Log
I expected the build to work and deploy to Cloudflares CDN
astro.config.mjs:
here
Info: i want to use ssr

can you edit your question to include your astro.config.js? if are you statically generating the site, this shouldn't happen. or you need edge functions to SSR (server-side-render) for something?

see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/cloudflare/, but basically if you're doing static site generation for your "simple blog", you shouldn't need the @astrojs/cloudflare adapter.

Modify your Astro project to use edge-compatible code that doesn't rely on Node.js internal packages like "stream".
If refactoring your code isn't feasible, you can enable Node.js compatibility by using this:
wrangler.toml

compatibility_flags = ["nodejs_compat"]
compatibility_date = "2024-09-23"

This flag allows your Worker to use Node.js built-in modules like "stream" in the Cloudflare Workers environment.
